# All-sky imaging camera recommendations

Tags: camera-recommendation, fisheye, sun, clouds

I am looking for a camera (with a fisheye lens) to capture low temporal resolution (0.1 Hz), reasonably high pixel resolution (1 mega pixel) video. It will be installed in a weather proofed housing pointed up to capture video of cloud motion. I plan to collect and stream the video via a 3G modem.

I am a novice and am looking for advice on what some considerations that I need to make are (handling glare from the sun, cameras with APIs for adjusting settings remotely, temperature tolerance etc.).

Comment: Product recommendation is off-topic here. You should probably make your question more about finding the right specifications than camera model.

Comment: If you're looking to take 10 fps that's really more along the lines of video.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MichaelClark actually need 1 frame every 10 seconds. I can do with 1 frame every 30 seconds.

Comment: @Olivier  I am really looking for advice on what I need to look for in a camera than a specific product recommendation. I will alter the question accordingly.

Comment: Are any obstructions allowed such as a pole, pillar, or light baffle?

Answer (score 2):

The first impulse is to point up with a ***fish-eye wide angle lens***.

I'm going to try get you to point down with a ***hemispherical mirror facing a normal lens***.

The cost advantage will be enormous. Maintenance year round will be easier. The downside is that the very centre of your sky view will contain the image of the camera itself albeit reduced in size considerably. You will need three (minimum) support uprights or boom to suspend the camera assembly and power and data cables. The cables can be run inside the supports.

Glare from the sun will be an issue as the luminance is considerable. At least you won't have the sun's direct focussed rays tracking across the sensor when exposed.

This kind of a setup, while not getting a lot of ooos and ahhhs, should be of sufficient quality to get much vector information about patterns.